# Global Object Definitions

Tags: python, class

```
class testClass(object):
  def __init__(self, val)
     self.val=val

def function():
  variable = "name"
  x="value"
  exec(str(variable) + "=testClass('" + str(x) + "')")

function()
print(name.val)
```

This is test code for a different algorithm I'm using. It returns a name error for the var 'name'. Even when I put the print(name.wins) inside of test(), I still receive a name error. The class is definitely being defined as if I put print("test") within the constructor of testClass(), it prints just fine. Why does this not work?

EDIT:
I opted to use a dictionary rather than dynamic variable names.

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: Should be fixed.

Comment: Anyway, you are `exec`ing your code inside a function. The variable you create will not be a global variable. You can pass `globals()` to `exec` which makes the local and global namespace `globals()`, so it will make a global variable. **But you really shouldn't be doing this at all**. Almost certainly, whatever you are trying to accomplish is better done in another way

Comment: I'm trying to create objects which I'll be accessing in many places in my code. What's wrong with globalising them?

Comment: have a look at this link:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec

Note the last comment:

Note The default locals act as described for function locals() below: modifications to the default locals dictionary should not be attempted. Pass an explicit locals dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on locals after function exec() returns.

This means you need to pass in a locals dictionary to receive the variable assignment.
check the dictionary after the exec() completes for the value.  also this is not a great practice as noted before.

Comment: if you need a set of configured values.  create a global dictionary and stick the items in their by key and use them by key.  its much much more clear what you are doing.

Comment: @Xaeol no, the problem is using `exec`. It is almost never the correct solution. And what you are doing here seems like completely the wrong use-case.

Comment: Is there an alternative to using exec in this way?  I'm using exec as I need to enter the name of each object through a variable and also reference these objects all throughout my code.

Comment: @Xaeol as was said by juanpa.   Its bad practice.  imagine someone seeing your code without noticing the assignment behavior you are using.   they would have little idea where 'name' came from and how to work with it.

Comment: @Xaeol create a dictionary in a constants module.  import that and use that dictionary as a global dictionary wherever you need it would be one way to do it.  so something like:
import constants; constants.GLOBA_DICT[name] = value; my_value = constants.GLOBAL_DICT[name];

etc

Comment: @LhasaDad In my actual code (this is just to test my syntax), I randomise the name of the object. It's a football simulation so I need randomly generated names for each player. Is this still bad practice?

Comment: @Xaeol going to say yes but tough to tell what your constraints are based on the current code snippet.  you can always get the keys of a dictionary to know the 'names' of the players you randomly generated.

Comment: @Xaeol fwiw,  in the example you have name.wins (in the example the wins attribute of the class is never shown as defined so even if you pass back the name the wins reference will also fail.

Comment: Thanks for the help! And that was meant to be 'name.val', apologies.

Comment: "It's a football simulation so I need randomly generated names for each player." I assume you have a Player class or similar then? Just keep the players in a `players` list (or dictionary if you'd like to refer to them by name).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the hidden wisdom *"It's a football simulation so I need randomly generated names for each player."* in the comments, maybe you're looking for something like this in the end:

```
import random


def generate_name():
    length = random.randint(3, 7)
    magic = random.randint(0, 7)
    name = ""
    for x in range(length):
        if (magic + x) % 2 == 0:
            name += random.choice("bcdghjkmnpqrstv")
        else:
            name += random.choice("aeiou")
    return name.title()


class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


def add_player(team):
    player = Player(name=generate_name())
    team.append(player)
    return player


# Could be a list of teams too...
team_1 = []
team_2 = []
for x in range(4):
    add_player(team_1)
    add_player(team_2)

for team_num, team in enumerate([team_1, team_2], 1):
    for player_num, player in enumerate(team, 1):
        print(f"Team {team_num} player {player_num}: {player.name}")
```

This prints out (e.g.; the names are random):

```
Team 1 player 1: Hecedak
Team 1 player 2: Aca
Team 1 player 3: Aniqo
Team 1 player 4: Osi
Team 2 player 1: Comet
Team 2 player 2: Kanerav
Team 2 player 3: Bovoro
Team 2 player 4: Cojov
```